# How to shrink down row width depending on the size of the columns - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">
    <div class="col-4 mr-2">
        <img class='img-fluid' src="<?php echo $user['profile_pic']; ?>" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="col-4 justify-content-center">
        <p>
            <?php echo $user['first_name'].' '.$user['last_name']; ?>
        </p>
        <p>
            <?php echo $user['num_posts']; ?>
        </p>
        <p>
            <?php echo $user['num_likes']; ?>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want the row to shrink it's width down to only the total width of the nested columns. Currently the columns don't fill the entire row. And some extra space is getting wasted. How do I shrink down the size of the row?

Answer (score 0):

You can use d-flex instead of row and col.

```css
*{
border: 2px dotted green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <p>The problem</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <p>is here</p>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="d-flex">
  <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
    <p>Hello World! This is wrapped to content</p>
  </div>
  <div class="d-flex flex-wrap">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```